# EF6 Cannot Convert Generic.List to Linq.IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, generics, entity-framework-6

I am writing a conditional query to return specific data from three different tables. The tables do not have direct relationship so I had to use joins.  I Also needed to group the data. This is What I have come up with:

```
    public static List<SimpleConfCommSchedule> GetSimpleConfCommSchedules(DateTime confCommSchedDate,
        short sessionId, string body = null)
    {
        using (var context = new ConferenceContext())
        {
            var confCommSched = context.ConferenceMemberSchedules
                .Join(context.ConferenceMembers,
                    s => s.AuditId,
                    m => m.AuditId,
                    (s, m) => new {s, m})
                .Join(context.Rooms,
                    sm => sm.s.RoomNumber.Value,
                    r => r.RoomId,
                    (sm, r) => new { sm, r });

            confCommSched = confCommSched.Where(smr => smr.sm.s.SessionId == sessionId && smr.sm.s.Deleted == false);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(body))
                confCommSched = confCommSched.Where(smr => smr.r.Body == body);

            confCommSched = confCommSched.GroupBy(smr => new { smr.sm.s.BillNumber, smr.sm.s.MeetingDateTime, smr.sm.s.AuditId, smr.r.Location })
                .Select(smr => new
                {
                    billNumber = smr.Key.BillNumber,
                    room = smr.Key.Location,
                    datetime = smr.Key.MeetingDateTime,
                    members = smr.Select(t => new
                    {
                        displayOrder = t.sm.m.DisplayOrder,
                        memberId = t.sm.m.MemberId
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList()
                .Select(obj => new SimpleConfCommSchedule
                {
                    BillNumber = obj.billNumber,
                    Location = obj.room,
                    MeetingStart = obj.datetime,
                    MemberIds = obj.members.Select(m => new SimpleMemberId
                    {
                        MemberId = m.memberId,
                        DisplayOrder = m.displayOrder
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();

            return confCommSched;
        }
    }
```

When I get to the GroupBy, I see an error that says I cannot convert from source type System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Linq.IQueryable.

What change do I need to make in the code to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. You have variable `confCommSched` which is of a different type than the result you are trying to assign to it with the last assignment (*where you are using your `GroupBy`*). The fix is simple, return the query result directly OR use a new variable.

```
var result = confCommSched.GroupBy(/* everything else unchanged in your query and lambda calls etc */ );
return result;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So when I use GroupBy, I am basically changing the type of data being returned?

Comment: @TravisLovellette - It's because of `ToList()` which returns type `List<T>` which is not assignable to `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification and the help, I greatly appreciate it.